# ConcurrentDictionary.Where very slow for filtering based int array (Key field)

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have the following

```
  var links = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Link>();
```

which is populated with around 20k records, I have another array of strings (List) that I turn into int array using following.

```
var intPossible = NonExistingListingIDs.Select(int.Parse); //this is very fast but need to be done
```

which is pretty fast. but I would like to create a new list or filter out "links" only to what is actually in the intPossible array which matches the Key element of the ConcurrentDictionary.

I have the following using a where clause but it takes about 50 seconds to do the actual filtering which is very slow for what I want to do.

```
var filtered = links.Where(x => intPossible.Any(y => y == x.Key)).ToList();
```

I know intersect is pretty fast but I have a array of ints and intersect is not working with this against a ConcurrentDictionary

How can i filter the links to be a little faster instead of 50 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace your O(n) inner lookup with something more speedy like a hashset which offers O(1) complexity for lookups.

So

```
var intPossible = new HashSet<int>(NonExistingListingIDs.Select(int.Parse));
```

and

```
var filtered = links.Where(x => intPossible.Contains(x.Key)).ToList();
```

This will avoid iterating most of `intPossible` for every item in `links`.

Alternatively, Linq is your friend:

```
var intPossible = NonExistingListingIDs.Select(int.Parse);
var filtered =
  links.Join(intPossible, link => link.Key, intP => intP, (link, intP) => link);
```

The implementation of Join does much the same thing as I do above.

Comment: The first version worked well, its in milliseconds now. thank you, waiting to mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Zoinky, yes... I expected so. The problem was probably compounded by the fact that your `intPossible` was not actually an array but an unmaterialized IEnumerable. Every time you iterated it with the call to `.Any`, it would have to reparse the strings in NonExistingListingIDs, which would add considerable burden to the operation. By putting it in a HashSet, it gets enumerated only once (but naturally requires more memory to store).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method would be to enumerate your list and use the indexer of the dictionary...might be a little cleaner...

```
var intPossible = NonExistingListingIDs.Select(int.Parse);
var filtered = from id in intPossible
               where links.ContainsKey(id)
               select links[id];
```

You might want to chuck in a `.ToList()` in there for good measure too...

This should actually be slightly faster than @spender's solution, since `.Join` has to create a new HashTable, whilst this method uses the HashTable in the ConcurrentDictionary.